# Jquery: stopping navigation into link when it has javascript embeded

Tags: jquery

When I am dealing with links with Javascript embeded,

```
<a onclick="return tnNav2Evt391(this,'');" href="#" class="">link</a>
```

I want to stop the execution of Javascript and highlight it.

With normal links without Javascript embeded, I am able to stop default navigation:

```
function processAction(e){  
    var clicked = e.target;
    switch(clicked.tagName)
    {
        case "A":       
            return false; // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('a').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefaut();
    //write the logic herer
});
```

It'll prevent click default event.

Comment: Note that this example will prevent the default action on every click. If you only want it on one link give a more specific selector.

Comment: It's not working. I think the inline handler is always executed first.

Comment: I updated the answer with a new code, I believe that now it'll work